# Xcode Accidentally Deleted Theme

Tags: xcode, ide

Is there a way to get a Xcode-packaged theme back if I accidentally deleted it? I deleted a theme entirely in the process of getting rid of redundant copies of that theme.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of color themes for Xcode (in fact, any text editor) on Github. This [repo](https://github.com/tursunovic/xcode-themes/tree/master/xcode-themes) has `Default.dvtcolortheme`, which is the default that came from Apple.

Choose one ([preview](https://github.com/tursunovic/xcode-themes)) and place it under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/`

Comment: thanks! I accidentally deleted the new 'Civic' IDE theme from the Xcode 8 beta. However, many of those themes on that linked GitHub account will suffice.